# How to extra variable from fetch response html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsing, fetch

i am using code to fetch body of another website and i need extra some available javascript variable from string

Here is code

```
fetch("https://testwebsite.com", {})
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => {
     
     const varAPI = ?? // extra variable from text response

     //const anotherVAR = ??;
     return $result;
  })
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

The html response text like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var varAPI = 'this is value needed';
        var anotherVAR = 'this is another value needed';

        //Some logic endpoint javascript
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you need to get a value from the API Response you get?

Comment: Are you trying to do something based on the values that your API returns?

Comment: `??` is the nullish coalescing operator - make it clearer that it's a mystery value rather than nullish coalescing

Comment: You can try to apply regex on the response text and extract the values.

Comment: Can you let me regex operator . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, but it's considered as a bad practice that leads to security risks.

```
fetch("https://testwebsite.com", {})
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(html => {
     const parser = new DOMParser();
     const dom = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
     
     eval(dom.querySelector('script').textContent); // <== execute remote js in the local context
     console.log("varAPI: ", varApi);

     return html;
  })
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: Yes this is bad for security. I think best is using regex from response string. Can any one let me regex string. Thanks .